# Why this div with a selector with fixed position can't change it's left property

Tags: html, css

I have an html file with a css selector called **holder2** with a fixed position, I don't understand why it can't vary its left property, it just let me change its top property. If I change the left property value the div will not change position.

```css
#translucent {
  background-color: orange;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.holder2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 3px solid red;
  top: 70px;
  left: 180x;
}

.holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 3px solid red;
  top: 70px;
  left: 190px;
}

.frame {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>The opacity Property</h1>
  <div class="holder2">
    <img style="" src="http://gallery.raccoonfink.com/d/7003-2/alien-head-128x128.png">
    <iframe class="frame" id="translucent"></iframe>
    <div class="bar" id="2">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="holder">
    <iframe class="frame" id="translucent"></iframe>
    <div class="bar" id="1"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Simple typo:  `left:180x;` should be `left:180px;`

Comment: This is type you should type "left: 180px;" instead "left: 180x;"

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple typo.

Replace

```
left:180x;
```

with

```
left:180px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the left: `180x` to `180px` in `holder2` class. Small **typo error**.

```css
#translucent {
  background-color: orange;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.holder2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 3px solid red;
  top: 70px;
  left: 180x;
}

.holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 3px solid red;
  top: 70px;
  left: 190px;
}

.frame {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>The opacity Property</h1>
  <div class="holder2">
    <img style="" src="http://gallery.raccoonfink.com/d/7003-2/alien-head-128x128.png">
    <iframe class="frame" id="translucent"></iframe>
    <div class="bar" id="2">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="holder">
    <iframe class="frame" id="translucent"></iframe>
    <div class="bar" id="1"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```